# SSIS package won't run on my machine only. Corruption Error (novice user)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am trying to run an SSIS package that will take census information and create charts. I keep getting an error that says, "There were erros while the package was being loaded. The package might be corrupted." I can get other people to run the package with no problems. I'm not sure where to start and I'm also new to SSIS. Any thoughts/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you running the package? Double clicking on a .dtsx file? Running a batch script? Something else? Open a command prompt window (Windows key + R then type cmd) From that window, type `dtexec.exe /?`

Comment: I'm double clicking on the .dtsx file, then right clicking on the package I want then clicking execute container.

Comment: So what happens when you run dtexec from the command prompt?